# how to do regression and classification in a same time?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression

I was thinking of doing a job including regression firstly, then doing the classification. I read lots of sources that are saying it is `Semi-Supervised learning` while I think it is not.
Imagine after doing regression we will reach to the graph below:
[image]

we know that there are 2 classes and now the goal is for prediction of the possibility of locating in class 1 or 2. It means that, for the next data that we have, we need to make a classification.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are just describing standard classification.

Take the image below, the model of the classification is the *decision boundary* found between the two classes. After we have found this model, using a classification algorithm (clustering or otherwise), for new data we can use it to predict which class the new data belongs to.

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue or let me know if something is unclear